# How to Create Django Form Choice List from Query in View?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form where I would like to use dynamic choice list from a query in my view.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

**views.py**

```
 getdata = MyModel.objects.filter(filter=filter)

 form = MyForm(request.POST or None,
              mylist=[( (getdata.id), (getdata.name) ) for choice in getdata]
```

when I run that I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'` error.

I know I can use `ModelChoiceField` and do the query in my form but for this specific case I would rather use the list generated in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None,
          mylist=[( (choice.id), (choice.name) ) for choice in getdata]
```

when you iterate like that be it in list comprehension, here or dict comprehension you need to think the same way you do when you write a for loop:

```
for choice in getdata:
    #do something
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`choice` is the individual item in each iteration, not `getdata`.

```
mylist=[( (choice.id), (choice.name) ) for choice in getdata]
```

Comment: Daniel, your feedback is always valuable and you are real asset for the Django/Python community around here. Thank you for your continuing work and help!