# Pass model objects to choices field in django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a model called `Student` that has a manytomany relationship with a model called `Courses`. I have another model called `Attend` in which I want to get all the courses the student is taking and pass it in as a select menu containing the courses the student is taking. I tried to get the id using the foreign key "student" and then get courses belonging to that student and put it in a list and pass it to choices but it didn't work obviously. I would like to know how I can get the courses belonging to the student to appear in the select menu.

Here is my model.

```
class Attend(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    time_signed_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    isSignedIn = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Below does not work, I get an error 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'id'

    #courses = User.objects.get(id=student.id).courses
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Your question seems duplicated. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672219/how-to-create-django-form-choice-list-from-query-in-view

Comment: @LaraChicharo I looked into that question and it seems like something I want, but I don't know what to do with the "mylist" that was passed into the form. The student can only choose one item from that list at a time. This is why I feel like having it done through the model, I could use it much more easily. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To render the courses the student is taking you should try using [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/).

If I understand correctly, you want a form that uses [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

> Allows the selection of one or more model objects, suitable for
>   representing a **many-to-many** relation.

```
class AttendForm(forms.Form):
    courses = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Courses.objects.filter(student__id=id))
```

That exapmple would only work to show the data to the user and then retrieving its choice. There is a slightly different approach to this case and that is using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm).

> Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form.

`ModelForm` is a "database driven" form in which you can perform many task involving calls to the database easily.

Note: The queryset I used in the example is just an example, you dont have to use it that way.